# How to solve this exercise about Oracle Triggers

Tags: oracle, triggers, business-rules

I have to solve this exercise about triggers:

> Consider the following relational database schema used to represent
> project information:
>
> Person (ID, Surname, Name, Nationality)
>
> Project (Name, Manager,
> StartingYear, NumPeopleInvolved, International)
>
> Personnel (Project, PersonID)
>
> Specify the triggers required in Oracle to maintain the following
> integrity constraints:
>
> a) The number of people involved in a project (attribute
> NumPeopleInvolved) must be consistent with the number of tuples
> entered in Personnel for that project
>
> b) If the project is international (the International attribute
> assumes only two values) then the project must involve at least two
> people of different nationalities

I have a problem with the b) part.

I don't know how to handle the case in which a given Project has no people involved. If I try to insert the first people, I can not have two people of different nationalities since I have only one people.

How should this situation be handled?

Should I use a statement level trigger? I have not experience with triggers so I still haven't understood well what I can / I can't do with one kind of trigger.

I tried this way but it's clearly not working as it should:

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsertPersonnelInternational
AFTER INSERT ON Personnel
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT ProjectName
    FROM Personnel INNER JOIN Project
    WHERE PersonID = :new.ID Project = Name

    SELECT International
    FROM Personnel INNER JOIN Project
      ON Project = Name

    SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumPersonnel
    FROM Personnel
    WHERE Project = :new.Project

    IF NumPersonnel >= 1 THEN
    BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumNationalities
        FROM Personnel INNER JOIN Person
        ON Project = ProjectName
        GROUP BY Nationality

        IF International THEN
            IF NumNationalities = 1 Then
            BEGIN
                raise_application_error(-1)
            END
        ELSE
            IF NumNationalities <> 1 THEN
            BEGIN
                raise_application_error(-1)
            END
        END
    END
END
```

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - Indeed.  I'm always surprised when instructors, trying to teach a technique, provide a scenario where that technique should not be used.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is with a compound trigger. With a compound trigger we avoid the problem of mutating tables which we would get from a row level trigger on PERSONNEL.

We keep track of each project which is referenced by each affected row in a DML statement (insert, update, delete) in an array. At the end of the statement we query those projects to find whether the project is international, and if it is to check the nationalities of its assigned personnel.

It might look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER international_project_trg
  FOR insert or update or delete ON personnel
    COMPOUND TRIGGER

  -- Global declaration
  type project_t is table of number index by personnel.project%type;
  g_project project_t; 

  BEFORE EACH ROW IS
  BEGIN
    CASE
      -- we don't care about the value here, we just what a set of distinct projects
      WHEN INSERTING THEN
        g_project(:new.project) := 1;
      WHEN UPDATING THEN
        g_project(:new.project) := 1;
      WHEN DELETING THEN
        g_project(:old.project) := 1;
    END CASE;
  END BEFORE EACH ROW;

  AFTER STATEMENT IS
    l_project personnel.project%type;
    l_country_cnt pls_integer;
    l_people_cnt pls_integer; 
  BEGIN
    l_project := g_project.first();
    
    while l_project is not null loop
      select count(distinct ppl.nationality)
             ,count(*) 
       into l_country_cnt
            ,l_people_cnt
       from personnel per
            join project prj on per.project  = prj.name
            join person  ppl on per.personid = ppl.id     
        where per.project = l_project
        and   prj.international = 'Y';
        
        if l_people_cnt <= 1 then
          -- either not international project or only one assigned person
          -- so we don't care
          null;
        elsif l_country_cnt <= 1 then
          raise_application_error(-20999, l_project ||' must have multi-national team membership');  
        end if;
        
        l_project := g_project.next(l_project);
        
    end loop;    
    
  END AFTER STATEMENT;

END international_project_trg;
```

Here is [a working demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c649f3369a21b4af558f3bd05b98d18e). You can see that although the trigger allows for an international project to have only one assigned person it throws an error when we add a second person of the same nationality. We can solve this by inserting rows in a special order, or better by inserting a set of rows. This is a problem with apply such business rules.

You can use the same approach (in the same trigger) to check that whether the number of assigned personnel meets the `Project.NumPeopleInvolved` rule.

---

Note: compound triggers arrived in Oracle 11gR1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I still don't know about compound triggers so I think that the exercise should be done whitout it, but thanks anyway !!

Answer (score 1):

When you have a row-level trigger on table `Personnel` then you cannot run any SELECT on table `Personnel` within the trigger - you will get an `ORA-04091: table PERSONEL is mutating ...` error.

I think your teacher is expecting something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ProjectConsistency
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON PROJECT
    FOR EACH ROW
    
    p_count INTEGER;
    n_count INTEGER;

BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO p_count
    FROM Personnel
    WHERE PROJECT = :new.NAME;
        
    IF :new.NumPeopleInvolved <> p_count THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20010, 'The number of people involved in a project must be consistent with the number of tuples entered in Personnel for that project');
    END IF;

    IF :new.International = 'YES' THEN
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Nationality)
        INTO n_count
        FROM Personnel
        WHERE PROJECT = :new.NAME;
        
        IF n_count < 2 THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20010, 'The project must involve at least two people of different nationalities')
        END IF;    
    END IF;

END;
```

In reality you would not implement such requirement with a trigger, you would use a PL/SQL procedure.

Attribute `NumPeopleInvolved` is useless, i.e. redundant. Typically you would solve it by

```
UPDATE PROJECT proj 
SET NumPeopleInvolved = 
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Personnel p
    WHERE PROJECT = :new.NAME)
WHERE NAME = :new.NAME;
```

Such an update could be done by a trigger, for example.

Actually you would need similar triggers also on table `Personnel` and `Person`, because the personel/persons may change and project would become inconsistent. I don't know whether this should be considered by the exercise.

Imagine, on person gets released, i.e. deleted from table Person:

- would the application raise an error - person cannot be released (what happens if the person dies by Corona :-))?
- would be project be invalid?
- would be project be automatically updated?

Then, you should **never** raise errors like `raise_application_error(-1)` - always let the user know what went wrong!

Comment: A trigger on PROJECT won't help, because it's DML action on PERSONNEL which we need to track. We can use a compound trigger to enforce the rules.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following should work with insertions, deletions and updates on table Personnel. It simply check and update the international consistency for each project whether the table Personnel is altered.

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateInternationalProject
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON Personnel
BEGIN
    SELECT name, international
    FROM Project
    AS ProjectInternational;

    FOR projectInfo IN ProjectInternational
    LOOP
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT nationality)
            AS numNationalities
        FROM Personnel INNER JOIN Person
        ON personId = id
        WHERE project = projectInfo.name;

        IF numNationalities = 1 THEN
            IF projectInfo.international THEN
                UPDATE Project
                SET international = 0
                WHERE name = projectInfo.name;
            END IF;
        ELIF numNationalities > 1 THEN
            IF NOT projectInfo.international THEN
                UPDATE Project
                SET international = 1
                WHERE name = projectInfo.name;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: This sets the values on PROJECT depending on the number of rows in PERSONNEL. But if you read the question more carefully you will see that the Seeker wants to **enforce** integrity constraints, that is the rows in PERSONNEL should identify PERSON records which match the rules defined in PROJECT.